# Linux thread id recycle strategy

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

What's the recycle strategy of Linux thread ID ?

Linux process ID will not be reused immediately unless new PID get the max limitation and being rewinded.

When I use pthread_self() to get thread id, I got TIDs like 1028, 1034. I guess it is the inner "serial number" of threads in a process. So I guess it would be more appropriate to use a thread id recycle strategy like PID recycle strategy.
But I am not quite sure whether it is true as to Linux pthread implementation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please take some time to read
[the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A threaded linux process has

1. an OS pid shared by all threads within the process - use `getpid`
2. each thread within the process has its own OS thread id - use `gettid`
3. a pthreads thread id used internally by pthreads to identify threads when making various pthread related calls - use `pthread_self` and similar.

It can't be determine from your question if you trying to implement a "recycle strategy" or why you think you need to do so.

**Edit**

As an idle curiosity you can look through the linux pthread code but technically you have no reason to care.  The POSIX spec basically just says the thread id is guaranteed to be unique within a process and is free to be reused after a thread dies.

> Although implementations may have thread IDs that are unique in a system, applications should only assume that thread IDs are usable and unique within a single process. The effect of calling any of the functions defined in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 and passing as an argument the thread ID of a thread from another process is unspecified. A conforming implementation is free to reuse a thread ID after the thread terminates if it was created with the detachstate attribute set to PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED or if pthread_detach() or pthread_join() has been called for that thread.

Comment: I am not trying to implement a TID "recycle strategy", just wandering if a thread id will be reused immediately or after new TID get max limitation and being rewinded.  Pardon my pool English.

Comment: I updated the answer.  As a practical matter I have never seen a pthreads implementation that immediately reused a thread id but I can't say I have been actively looking for it either.

Answer (score 1):

In linux threads are implemented as processes (with shared memory and other stuff)
so the kernel thread ids (the ones you get through gettid()) are really process ids.

This is also indicated by the fact that the id of first thread of a process and that process' id are one and the same.

Now i don't know exactly what is the pid-allocation algorithm employed by the linux kernel, but i believe it makes some effort to avoid rapid pid reuse (i think i have read about that somewhere but cant remember).

Note that those are the *kernel* thread ids (returned by the syscall gettid()), which is different thing from the "pthread_t" (returned by the library function pthread_self()).
While both can be used to uniquely identify threads, the former is linux-specific, so if your code needs to be portable you better avoid it (or use #ifdef-s).